# Positioning elements CSS

Tags: css-float, css

I recently start to learn CSS and table less design.
After reviewing some tutorials now I am involved with converting PSD Mockup to XHTML and CSS.
Most often my problem is to positioning elements and containers.
for example this below design:

I am converting this to CSS and HTML.
I have no problem with styling Input elements.
about main layout it seems two columns layout , right ?
How do I style containers ? 
I wrote this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/xNwAc/1/) It displays better [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xNwAc/1/show/).
I divided my page to two containers and valued (float:left) to left container.
As specified in jsFiddle link elements on the left side container had come out of the box (I think its because of float).
I can't set containers position to absolute.

Now please help me to refactor and change my code.
 And please explain to me how to position elements right ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think a

> `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`

before the `</div>` of the container will work.

edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/xNwAc/5/

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a new formating context on the container, with `overflow:auto;` eg.
I sugger you to read [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) which is very clear and useful.

As the exclamation point is not a part of the content you can place it as a background image.

Answer (score 1):

Try and have a wrapping element to contain your two columns. with W3C code, you'll want to use floated elements. The elements don't have any padding, you can work on them yourself, but it's a very basic structure to follow:

The CSS:

```
#wrapper { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; background: blue; } /* positions it center of page */
#left { float: left; width: 50%; background: red;}
#right { float: right; width: 50%; background: green;}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="left"> Left content </div>
   <div id="right"> Right content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm Thanks.. I have a question . Why in my code content is out of box but in  yours not ?

Comment: Then I should devide right container to two sections ? Because of the ("!").

Comment: You can define height: 100% to #wrapper, #left, and #right and see what happens. It's a basic structure, so it's dependent on what content you have their. Any problems, try adding overflow:hidden; to a element.